# How to get difference between first and last table row?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have the following table:

```
ID  val  DateTime  
1   20   2018-12-11 14:57:20.620   
2   30   2018-12-11 20:57:20.940
3   15   2018-12-12 00:57:20.460
4   41   2018-12-12 04:57:20.830
5   22   2018-12-12 11:57:20.077
```

Also, I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[C_PS_PS]
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @DataStart datetime=null,
 @DataStop  datetime=null
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT [ID]
      ,[val]
      ,[DateTime]
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[C_Tbl]
  WHERE DateTime between @DataStart and @DataStop
END

execute [C_PS_PS] '2018-12-11 14:57:20.620','2018-12-12 11:57:20.077'
```

When I execute it, I get the the above table. My question is: how can I get the difference of `val` between first and last row depending the on `DataStart` and `DataStop`?

To exemplify what I want, let's say I want to get the difference of val for the record with date `2018-12-11 20:57:20.940` and `2018-12-12 04:57:20.830`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. `cte` brings the oldest date and its `val` and `cte2` brings the newest date and its `val`. Then finally use a `cross join` and subtract `cte.val` from `cte2.val` (or vice-versa):

```
;with cte as
(
    select top 1 [DateTime], val from [dbo].[C_Tbl] 
    WHERE [DateTime] between @DataStart and @DataStop
    order by [DateTime] asc
),
cte2 as
(
    select top 1 [DateTime], val from [dbo].[C_Tbl] 
    WHERE [DateTime] between @DataStart and @DataStop
    order by [DateTime] desc
)
select  
cte.[DateTime], cte2.[DateTime], cte.val, cte2.val,
--DATEDIFF( dd , cte.[DateTime], cte2.[DateTime]) 'difference_days' 
cte.val-cte2.val
from cte cross join cte2
```

Comment: I don't want to make the difference of the dates, but difference between 41 and 30 from val column.

Comment: I've edited my response. Add column `val` to both `cte`s and then subtract with `cte.val-cte2.val` instead of using `datediff`.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[C_PS_PS]
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @DataStart datetime=null,
 @DataStop  datetime=null
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
;WITH VALUES_START_END AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM C_Tbl WHERE [DateTime] = @DataStart
    UNION 
    SELECT TOP 1 -VAL FROM C_Tbl WHERE [DateTime] = @DataStop
)

SELECT [ID]
      ,[val]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,ABS(T.VAL_DIFF_BETWEEN_SART_END)VAL_DIFF_BETWEEN_SART_END
  FROM [C_Tbl]
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(VAL) VAL_DIFF_BETWEEN_SART_END FROM VALUES_START_END)T
  WHERE DateTime between @DataStart and @DataStop
END
GO
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to make the difference of the dates, but difference between 41 and 30 from val column.

Comment: VAL_DIFF_BETWEEN_START_END showing the difference of 20 and 22 as per the start_data and end_data parameter...try giving other date parameter values.